# #id not selecting my image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, border

I want to border an image, and when I code it in HTML, I get a border. But when I try it in CSS, the border will be placed south-west on my page, seperated from my image.

```
<img id="maxaboutme" />
<img src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg" 
height="300px" />
```

CSS

```
#maxaboutme{    
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 15px;      
}
```

This is what happens :

[image]

Comment: Change `maxaboutme` to `#maxaboutme` in your CSS. `#` is the CSS id selector

Comment: You have two different elements for starters.  It should be `<img id="maxaboutme" src="urlhere" />` Then the CSS should target the id using `#` so `#maxaboutme { *CSS here* }`

Answer (score 2):

Change your img tag as shown below  :(In your case ,you had 2 of them which were not related to each other )

```
 <img id="maxaboutme"
         src="http://www.google.com/selfdrivingcar/images/home-where.jpg" height="300px" />
```

CSS :

```css
#maxaboutme
{
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
 <img id="maxaboutme"
         src="http://www.google.com/selfdrivingcar/images/home-where.jpg" height="300px" />
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/n85z5Lsw/)

Comment: why giving same answer which is given above also?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have added another image (`<img id="maxaboutme" />`) instead of applying the `id` to

```
<img src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg" height="300px" />
```

Modify your HTML as below.

```css
#maxaboutme {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<img id="maxaboutme" src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg" height="300px" />
```

Comment: I have that. I have the # infront of maxaboutme.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like that. By the way I recommend you to use class instead of id ;)

```css
#maxaboutme{
  border: solid 15px grey;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img id="maxaboutme" src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

CSS:

```
#maxaboutme{

  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 15px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="maxaboutme" src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg" height="300px" />
```

Pleae note: avoid using physical paths (C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\maxpannenkoekenhuisHTML01.jpg) for your images because it will work on your computer only and it will not work for your client

Answer (score 0):

It's working. I had an extra IMG indeed.

I am still new and also learning from the paths.

Comment: you can select any answer from above which helped you to solve answer..also please dont add comments in answer..please delete the Comment

Answer (score 0):

html tag should be :

```
<img id="yourimage" src="http://placeit.org/300x300.jpg"/>
```

css :

```
#yourimage {

border: 1px solid gray;
height: 300px; 

}
```

hope it would be helpful.